# How do I move my app that I built with Google App Engine to an Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Basically, I built a python application using Google App Engine SDK on my Mac.  I moved it over to my Ubuntu server, set up python to run in apache, installed webapp2 and my application just shows a blank page.  My assumption is that this has to do with Google App Engine.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps built using the App Engine SDK are designed to be served from Google's App Engine environment.  You need to deploy the app to App Engine.

The current deployment instructions are [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp#deploying_an_app)

Alternatively, `webapp2` applications can be run outside of the App Engine environment; there's a quickstart guide [here](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html).  Storage on the App Engine platform is independent of `webapp2`, so you'd need to find a new storage solution: a relational or non-relational database and possibly an ORM to simplify data persistence and retrieval.  Your model layer would need to be modified accordingly.

You should also need to remove App Engine files such as `appengine_config.py`, `app.yaml` and other App Engine yaml config files as they will no longer be used by your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This might be a stupid follow up question, but how would I go about making this webapp2 application work outside of Google's App Engine?

Comment: I followed the guide you posted, but I'm trying to run this on my server that I'm hosting on a VPS, so using the host 127.0.0.1 won't work.  I've tried all sorts of stuff and just can't this to work.  It's probably worth noting as well, that I'm not trying to run this as the root.  I have a PHP site, and I want this python program to run from a sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run your app just like you run it on your Mac you can install the Linux GAE or Goggle Cloud SDK and run the app in it.

But if you want production quality/performance the only option I know of (without re-writing the app) is to use [AppScale](https://www.appscale.com/).